# How to getdate java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

How to fix this code? What should i use instead of integer %d while i'm working with dates?

```
public static void entryAdd()
    {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" Student Number  :");
        int newNumber= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" Entry no  :");
        int entryNumber=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" Borrow Date :");
        int borrowDate=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Return Date :");
        int returnDate=scan.nextInt();
        try{
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
            String query=String.format("insert into entry values( %d, %d, %d, %d, %d)", newNumber,entryNumber,borrowDate, returnDate);
            int add = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println("Entry Added");
        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}

    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use string to instead of date, in MySQL you could insert string date. MySQL will change it to real date.

```
public static void entryAdd()
{
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(" Student Number  :");
    int newNumber= scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(" Entry no  :");
    int entryNumber=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(" Borrow Date :");
    String borrowDate =scan.next();
    System.out.print("Return Date :");
    String returnDate =scan.next();
    try{
        PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into entry values( ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        stmt.setInt(1, neNumber);
        stmt.setInt(2, entryNumber);
        stmt.setString(3, borrowDate);
        stmt.setString(4, returnDate);
        int i=stmt.executeUpdate();   
        System.out.println("Entry Added");
    }catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally() {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But this line should be  String query=String.format("insert into entry values( %d, %d, %s, %s)", newNumber,entryNumber,borrowDate, returnDate);

Comment: This is unsafe, the proper solution is to use a prepared statement with parameter place holders. Concatenating (or interpolating) string values from untrusted sources into a query string makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. And in this case, your solution will lead to a syntax error.

Comment: Well, you are correct, but this is only for a small java program to learn statement. If you want it perfect you should also close the connection in the finally block. Just modified the answer to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `String.format` to construct a query string. When used with string values (or other objects), it can make your code susceptible to SQL injection or hard to diagnose syntax errors.

The proper solution is something along the lines of:

```
// ...
// You may need to use `DateTimeFormatter` with a specific format, this will use yyyy-MM-dd
LocalData borrowDate = LocalDate.parse(scan.next())
LocalData returnDate = LocalDate.parse(scan.next())
try (Statement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
        "insert into entry (newNumber, entryNumber, borrow, return) values (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    stmt.setInt(1, newNumber);
    stmt.setInt(2, entryNumber);
    stmt.setObject(3, borrowDate);
    stmt.setObject(4, returnDate);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

This assumes that you're inserting into a `DATE` column, and that your driver is JDBC 4.2 compliant.

I'm also explicitly specifying the columns to insert (I have guessed the column names based on your variable names). This protects you against problems with inserting into reordered columns, or table changes where (nullable) columns have been added.